# TeXLive 2019 (MacTeX): Lualatex can't find any image with \includegraphics

Tags: luatex, mactex, includegraphics, texlive-2019

Running MacTex 2019, all packages updated, and suddenly every `\includegraphics` instance returns the following error:

`Package luatex.def Error: File 'path/to/file' not found: using draft setting.`

I haven't any clue about what's going on except this other post about a similar issue with MiKTeX: [MiKTeX graphics version 1.3b bug on Windows 10 (\set@curr@file undefined)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined)

Every file I tried was compiling fine a month ago or so.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is this the exact error message? In this case, you may have forgotten to replace the string `path/to/file` with the actual path to your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, `path/to/file` was just a placeholder.

But I found the exact problem and possible workarounds while it is fixed.

My exact problem is described here: [grffile & lualatex does not work together anymore (Oct 2019)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513517/grffile-lualatex-does-not-work-together-anymore-oct-2019)

And here is the discussion on Github: https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/73

A temporary workaround is explained here: https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/73#issuecomment-543101052

Comment: note that no one other than you could have answered your question as you hadn't even mention grffile in the question.

Comment: I am very sorry about that. But, by the time I wrote my first message I didn't have any clue about what was going on. Further research pointed me to that direction, the interaction between grffile and lualatex. I mark the post as answered in case it is useful to anyone. My apologies.

Comment: sure: no harm done really but just to explain why questions should almost always include a complete small document that shows the error. Then you don't need to guess what the issue is, people can see it and debug.